# show loading icon while processing a web page

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My MainActivity calls  HandleWebPage.init() to download and parse a web page link. After init() call, I will get set of strings (3 strings) . Each string is shown in a separate fragment (default first fragment with first string). Other fragments can be selected via navigation drawer.

Issue is I am trying to add progress dialog which should show loading icon (rotating circle) till Handle Webpage.init() gets completed.

init() function internally calls 2 async tasks ; One to download the web page and second is to process the web page using jsoup to get above strings.

How can I add progress dialog to while init() function getting processed and returned to MainActivity?

I have tried adding init() in AsyncTask and putting progress dialog in onPreExecution etc.., did not work.
Also tried to create progressdialog.show() then create a thread and started and called init()
did not work.
I would like to know what would be right solution
Below is code snippet.

```
MainActivity.java /// ------------snip
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            updateYearMonthDay();  //gets year, month, day
            //hwp is instance of HandleWebPage class
            // hwp.init() internally downloads a webpage and process
            // This takes some time and I require to show some progress around this
            hwp.init(year, month, day);  
            // after complete i get 3 strings which is processed further in below function
            updateMetaData();
            // this show first fragment with fist string in text view.
            SelectItem(0);

        }

HandleWebPage.java
--------------------
public void init()
{
           doc = downloadPage();
           if (doc != null) {
                  extractlinks(doc);
           }
// some other function which uses AsyncTask as 
String = new getmoreInfo().execute(dataString1).get();
}

public Document downloadPage()
{
try {
        doc = new getWebPage().execute(urlString).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;       
}

public class getWebPage extends AsyncTask<String, Document , Document> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).timeout(0).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(doc == null) {
            return null;
        } else
            return doc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc1) {
        super.onPostExecute(doc1);
    }
};

public void extractLinks(Document doc)
{
// code to process doc using jsoup and update respective String in this class.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably merge the two `AsyncTask`s that you perform sequentially into a single AsyncTask. For showing a progressbar during the `AsyncTask`, initialize the progressbar with a visibility of `GONE` when the activity is created. Then set the visibility to `VISIBLE` in the `onPreExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` and set it back to `GONE` in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: thank you. You mean, I need to create a AsyncTask in MainActivity and move hwp.init() in doInbackground() of this and show progress dialog in onPreExecute() and dismiss it onPostExecute() ??. This means calling AsyncTask From MainActivity where doInBackground() which internally calls another AsyncTask (via hwp.init()) right..?

Comment: Yeah, except you need not call another AsyncTask from the doInBackground of first AsyncTask - you can remove the AsyncTask from init() method

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and see if I am getting expected result